# while loop problem in r

Tags: r

i am trying to get this loop in my r program to work but it is not giving me the results that I desire. I am trying to model an insurance contract where there are n securities that have a fixed likelihood of default vector(data[i,2]) and a payout vector(data[i,1]).

i need to price the value of stop losses at the security level and at the portfolio level. to do this i created two while loops for the conditional vectors of each level (which will be inputed into the function by the user) one while loop to scan through the various securities and a final one to model the various scenarios. i tried to Use R's matrix capabilities to help organize the results.

the problem with this code is that the if statement behaves oddly, not activating and filtering correctly. this causes the program to be slow and provide bad results. it fills the individual protection column always rather than conditioning it on the likelihood vector(data[i,2]). there is a lot of moving parts but overall it is a simple model.

```
 y = years
nr=nrow(data1)
nc=ncol(data1)
isl =  individualStopLoss
asl = aggregateStoploss
Lasl = length(asl)
LIsl = length(isl)
claims = vector(mode = "logical",length= asl)
 individualProtection = matrix(0,ncol=LIsl,nrow=y)
 aggregateProtection = matrix(0,ncol=Lasl ,nrow=y)
expectedClaims = data1[,1]*data1[,2]
expectedClaims = sum(expectedClaims)
k = 1
m=1
    while (k<=y)
        {j = 1
         m = 1
         runi = runif(nr, min=0, max=1)
         while (m<=Lasl)
            {while (j<=LIsl)
                     {i=1
                       while (i<=nr) 
                           {if ( runi[i] < data1[i,2] )
                               {individualProtection[k,j] = individualProtection[k,j] + max(data1[i,1]-isl[j],0) 
                               claims[k] = claims[k] + data1[i,1]
                               i=i+1
                                }
                                else{i= i+1}
                           }
                        j=j+1
                     }        
            aggregateProtection[k,m]= aggregateProtection[k,m] + max(claims[k] - expectedClaims*asl[m],0)
            m = m+1
            }
        k = k+1
        }
```

Comment: (1) Making your example reproducible, so that others can actually run your code, would help a lot. Try providing a small amount of your data (data1, years, isl, asl). (2) If you think the if statement isn't evaluating right, you can always throw some cat() statements in to verify what runi[i] and data1[i,2] are as the program runs.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified numerical example of what you would expect your result vectors, `aggregateProtection` and `claims` to be given `data1[i,1] = 1,2,3` and `data1[i,2] = 3,2,1` or something similar that provides a more explicit explanation of the numbers you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

Just an example to help you provide a reproducible example, will be deleted when your question is updated.

```
data1 <- cbind(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))
y = sample(rep(1990:2011,1000),1000)
nr=nrow(data1)
nc=ncol(data1)
isl =  rnorm(500)
asl = rnorm(500)
Lasl = length(asl)
LIsl = length(isl)
```